# Rendering "IMFMediaBuffer" using DirectX 11 APIs

Tags: directx-11, ms-media-foundation

I am following details as given in below link for creating DirectX 11 Device and using it for rendering:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn643747(v=vs.85).aspx

This example demonstrates rendering cube in the video window.
But I want to render Video Buffer using this example.

I have `IMFMediaBuffer` which is having video frame read from a file.
I want to decode this buffer and then display it using DirectX 11 APIs.
I can decode this buffer using decoder, but not sure how to render it.

Answer (score 3):

Obtain the IMFDXGIBuffer interface from your IMFMediaBuffer via QueryInterface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447901(v=vs.85).aspx. Use GetResource to access the ID3D11Texture2D wrapped by this media buffer. Store the sub resource index using GetSubresourceIndex. Use ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476394(v=vs.85).aspx), by specifying the stored sub resource index as SrcSubresource parameter, to copy the obtained ID3D11Texture2D as pSrcResource parameter, to your device's swapchain (set in pDstResource). Call Present(1) of your swapchain.

```
CopySubresourceRegion(pSwapChain, 0, 0, 0, 0, pTexture2D, index, NULL);
```

Note: You should set the same D3D11 device via IMFDXGIDeviceManager to the decoder for this to work.

More details:

```
ComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> buffer;
CHK(sample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &buffer));

// Get the MF DXGI buffer
ComPtr<IMFDXGIBuffer> dxgiBuffer;
if (FAILED(buffer.As(&dxgiBuffer)))
{
    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> texture;
    unsigned int subresource;
    CHK(dxgiBuffer->GetResource(IID_PPV_ARGS(&texture)));
    CHK(dxgiBuffer->GetSubresourceIndex(&subresource));

    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
    texture->GetDevice(&device);
    device->GetImmediateContext(&context);

    context->CopySubresourceRegion(m_pSwapChain, 0, 0, 0, 0, texture.Get(), subresource, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will it be possible to provide sample API calls OR example for this, it will be more helpful.

Comment: I added a more detailed sample at the end of the answer.

Comment: @VuVirt - I noticed in the MSDN documentation that 'CopySubresourceRegion' does not allow stretching. Do you have any advice on how to stretch the image between the decoder and 'CopySubresourceRegion'?

Comment: @GaryG. Instead of using CooySubResourceRegion you can render a textured quad using the decoder texture. This quad can be rendered with scaling/stretching onto your render target.

Comment: On Windows Server 2016 interface IMFDXGIBuffer cannot be found.. with Media Foundation feature installed .. is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @iz25 "Minimum supported server Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps | UWP apps]" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfdxgibuffer